# How to move specific files with changes from one repository to another?

Tags: git, repository

I have two repositories, the first wallet 1 and the second wallet 2. In the wallet1 repository, a feature has been added, this feature needs to be moved to the wallet2 repository. Since this feature has been in the wallet1 repository for a long time, there have already been many commits to fix and improve it, so git cherry-pick is not suitable for this. They suggested that this can be done using “build diff”. Can anyone tell me what this is, or another way, a manual transfer option (copying a file and adding it to the repository is not very good)

I tried cherry-pick, but the commits couldn’t be collected into a heap, development and changes were carried out there for two years. I need to move 2 files from the wallet1 repository (there is such a file and location in both wallet1 and wallet2) with code changes in them and 4 new files

Comment: Okay. If you don't care about the history of the file (the commits) then copy it.

Comment: You can just copy it, I left it as a last resort if I can’t find a way to do it differently